# gulp replace task not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, gulp

I am building an Ionic App with AngularJS and i have a gulp task that should replace data in a file. The task executes without errors but it doesnt replace the data it is meant to replace. Its like nothing executed.

```
gulp.task('replace', function () {  
  // Get the environment from the command line
  var env = args.env || 'localdev';

  // Read the settings from the right file
  var filename = env + '.json';

  var settings = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config/' + filename, 'utf8'));
  console.log(settings.apiUrl)
// Replace each placeholder with the correct value for the variable.  
  gulp.src(paths.replace)  
    .pipe(replace({
      patterns: [
        {
          match: 'apiUrl',
          replacement: settings.apiUrl
        }
      ]
    }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/services'));
  console.log("here")
});
```

js/constants.js file

```
angular.module('loanstreet.constants',[])   
    .constant('apiUrl', '@@apiUrl');
```

localdev.json

```
{
  "apiUrl":"http://10.0.3.2:3000"
}
```

Upon replacing the apiUrl value, it should create and send to the destination .js/services/constants.js but it also doesnt create that as well.

Any recommendations because I honestly cant see what is wrong with the code. Any help appreciated.

Comment: is source file , what you've given is correct?

Comment: Is the `replace()` used in your code gulp-replace?

Comment: I believe the plugin used in this case is [gulp-replace-task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace-task) which is based on [applause](https://github.com/outaTiME/applause).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace), the parameter you're using is wrong.

It should be `replace(pattern, replacement)`

Also I think the `match` value is wrong in your example. It will replace the key *and* value. You need the @@ in the matcher.

Change it to

```
.pipe(replace('@@apiUrl', settings.apiUrl))
```

If you need to replace multiple things then chain more calls to `replace()`

```
.pipe(replace('@@apiUrl', settings.apiUrl))
.pipe(replace('@@another', 'foo'))
.pipe(replace('@@more', 'bar'))
```

Comment: i failed to mention tht i am following this tutorial http://geekindulgence.com/environment-variables-in-angularjs-and-ionic/

Comment: I believe the plugin used in this case is [gulp-replace-task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace-task) which is based on [applause](https://github.com/outaTiME/applause)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change the line:

```
gulp.src(paths.replace)
```

To:

```
gulp.src('./js/constants.js')
```

Or otherwise tell us what value `paths.replace` has at this moment.

Comment: paths.replace has './js/constants.js' at d moment

Comment: Do you get any output of the `console.log()` you have added?

Comment: yes the console output is correct but the weird part is it doesnt change neither does it create d dest file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `gulp-replace-task` was used I was getting the same thing where the task executes without errors but no replacement of data occures.

```
env: windows
node: v10.14.1
gulp: 3.9.1
```

In the end I resorted to using [applause.](https://github.com/outaTiME/applause)

Hence in the above the code would be something like:

```
applause      = require('applause'),
.... 

var settings = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config/' + filename, 'utf8'));
var options = {
  patterns: [
    {
      match: 'apiUrl',
      replacement: settings.apiUrl
    }
  ]
};

var applauseRunner = applause.create(options);
var result = applauseRunner.replace(content);

// Do something with the result.content (i.e. pipe to stream)
```

Hope this helps someone.